# JQuery not working at all

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know that you're not simply meant to link to your non-fictional site, but I don't really have any alternative as I simply cant see what is wrong, it could be anything.

My JQuery was working perfectly until I ran all my code through 'dirtymarkup.com', now absolutely no Jquery works.

I'm sure you've had those days where you just want to put your fist through the screen, this is one for me - so massive thanks to anyone who can help.

http://litefile.net/NOTWORKING/

Comment: jQuery 1.5.1? It's 2014...

Comment: Sorry, was just messing around with the JQuery version to see if I could get it to work. Changed to latest again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the textarea in line 215 needs a closing tag

**bad:**

```
<textarea/>
```

**good:**

```
<textarea></textarea>
```

Comment: You're actually the best. I've been ripping my hair out for an hour now and couldn't spot it. Thank you so much.